# Interpretation of partial autocorrelogram function

Tags: time-series

The partial autocorrelogram function for the time series I am working with shows a significant spike at lag 1 and a minor one at lag 3. For another time series, it shows the significant one also at lag 1 and another one at lag 6. How do I interpret this in terms of the time persistence of the series?

Comment: post your data.

Comment: World
3.938778488
3.940091294
4.209060429
6.806065336
6.289135202
7.206773191
7.040203117
7.006369822
9.422525827
14.78167006
12.08543594
11.85049286
6.096991494
8.274836551
10.90349004
13.18041154
20.17498689
29.03911562
36.56050186
46.19967533
46.8956634
38.23858744
38.48410819
44.91172889
52.64530876
65.11802409
70.5930687
83.71220182
119.497105
187.510739
205.0370008
103.1435646
82.19722524
88.96659363
145.0188001
131.0793709
218.0340534
340.8520813
270.3304434
174.3270871
216.1603205
247.105952
198.7762798

Comment: I cannot copy and paste the charts. It might be because I am using XLSTAT...

Comment: Is the seasonality is 1?

Answer (score 0):

The data has a major change(maybe you should include a causal that explains the large bumps in the data?) and the model before period 19 is different after period 19.  This will "cloud" your ACF/PACF.  If you use the Chow test you can identify a break in the model and then using the last 25 observations, a difference model with an outlier at period 38. I ran this with Autobox(I am affiliated).

[(1-B**1)]Y(T) = +[X1(T)][(1-B**1)][(+ 96.6698)]   :PULSE            38
                +          +   [A(T)]

[image: Actual, fit, forecasts]

Comment: Many thanks. I downloaded the trial version of Autobox a few weeks ago but it gave me a lot of problems and had to desinstall it. Do you recommend applying the Chow test assuming that the breaks are in period 19 and 38? Thanks again

Comment: Did you send an email or call?  I will say not.  FYI:You need to be installed as an admin....otherwise it won't work.  There is just one break being identified.  The period 38 is just an outlier.

Comment: No, I did not as I am pressed for time. It interfered with excel downloads. Thanks for the clarification on the admin issue and on the break point.